# Send the device token to a server's MySQL database

Tags: objective-c, ios

According to an [**article**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12), the method below can be used to get the device token. I want to ask how can I send this token to a server's MySQL database?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

Comment: why not just save it in NSUserDefault?

Comment: When you say "MySQL", this sounds like you want to save it on a server? So you're asking _How can I send something to a server_?

Comment: @Lunayo what use would a remote notification token be if stored locally on the device?

Comment: @BenjieGillam I thought he want to save it in local database, So what you want is send the device token through web service to server?

Comment: If you're looking for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` then that's deprecated now, but you can use the alternative suggested here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW12

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

First you must figure out a way to get it to your server. HTTP/HTTPS is the most standard way these days.

Then you must write code on your server that can store the value to MySQL. PHP is a popular language for doing this sort of thing. (Don't forget to create your MySQL tables/etc.)

Then you tell your client to send the data to your HTTP server to store in MySQL. You can do so by doing a POST (or GET if you prefer) via a `NSMutableURLRequest` (and related methods `NSURLConnection`, `NSURL`, ...) and doing `setHTTPBody:deviceToken`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, could you please advise some reference on "How to send data to server"? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes - look into the `NSMutableURLRequest` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html